# Nginx: How to reset connection when response time too long?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a problem with nginx reverse proxy, sometime i have got 502 BAD GATEWAY with log:

```
*63071 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream...
```

So i found a temporary solution, reset connection when response time too long (over 5 seconds). Anyone can tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, this is my config:

```
upstream backend {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx max_fails=2 fail_timeout=3s;
    #If waiting time greater than 3s and don't receive response from backend, try to reconnect.
}

server {
listen 80;
....
proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout in the nginx configuration.

If the error is generated because the proxy takes too long to connect (for example because the backend is down) you can use [`proxy_connect_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout) (from the docs: *Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server*.)

If the error is generated because the proxy takes too long to send data (for example because the backend is taking too much time to retrieve it) the you can use [`proxy_read_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) (from the docs: *Defines a timeout for reading a response from the proxied server. The timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole response. If the proxied server does not transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.*)